# Extract cleverly keywords from a text

Tags: java, text-mining, search-keywords

I analyse some press reviews with a java program, using Boilerpipe. I use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to extract keywords from the text.

My problem is that I have some Enterprises (WHO, Total, 2A, SEE, ARE...) I also need to extract, and as you can see, their name also exist as common words, so I get some "who, see, are"... results, despite the article doesn't speak about the enterprises. Have you got any idea how I could solve the problem (maybe like analysing the neighborhood of the word...) ?

Comment: It is too-broad. You are asking for machine learning algorithms!

Comment: You can check the casing of the abbreviations (they will generally be all uppercase) and analyse the previous and next words in such cases. For example "The ARE" can be identified as an enterprise because ARE is uppercase and the word before it is the definite article.

Comment: @Abhishek I had a feeling that was too large, but I still wanted to ask the question, maybe I'd have missed something. ^^

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri I also thought about case-sensitivity, seems it's the best solution. :)